# How to make proguard treat zip file as a resource?

Tags: java, proguard

I pass proguard a directory of all my class files and resources, pre-merged. Some of those resources are zip files.

Unfortunately, proguard handles zip files specially, expanding them into the final jar. [This is documented](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html):

> Each input entry can be:
>
> - A class file or resource file,
> - ...
> - A zip file, containing any of the above,
> - A directory (structure), containing any of the above.

The solution I use now is to pre-zip everything, forcing proguard to not recurse into zip files.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The packaging strategy can't be changed. You could change the extension of the zip file, so it is treated as a resource file, or you could indeed prepackage the zip file in another zip file or jar file.